# Visual Basic Excel Macro MessageBox.Show Throws "Object Required" Error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, messagebox, vba

Simply put no matter how hard I try I cannot get a MessageBox to appear through my Excel macro.

Here is the line I have so far:

```
MyBox = MessageBox.Show("Stuff", "Title")
```

When I run this macro I get the following error:

> Run-time error '424':
>   Object required

What's going on!?!?

Here is the complete code:

```
Sub ImportParser()
'
' ImportParser Macro
' By: Dennis Plotnik (July 2013)

'
    Dim ToKeepSize As Integer   ' Size of ToKeep array
    Dim BlankCount As Integer   ' Counts blank lines so as to stop execution after EOF
    Dim ReqText As String       ' Required String
    ReqText = "Import Control"
    BlankCount = 0
    ToKeepSize = -1
'    Dim ToKeep As String()
    Dim ToKeep() As String      ' Array to store names of tables that include required text
    Dim CurrentTable As String  ' String to store last required table name

    Range("B1").Select
    Do
        Do                      ' Go down until come to non-blank row (or exit if all blank)
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Dim tempS As String
            tempS = "'" + ActiveCell.Formula
            ActiveCell.Value = tempS
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop Until BlankCount > 15
        If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, ReqText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then  ' Check for ReqText in current cell
'            ActiveCell.Value = "HELLO!"                                ' For DEBUG purposes
            ToKeepSize = ToKeepSize + 1                                 ' Increment size of array (to allow for new value)
            ReDim Preserve ToKeep(ToKeepSize)
            Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select                              ' Move left to retrieve name of table (category)
            CurrentTable = ActiveCell.Value
            ToKeep(ToKeepSize) = CurrentTable
            For j = 0 To 10000
                Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select                           ' Cycle down until new table is reached
                Do
                    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                        BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
                        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop Until BlankCount > 15

                If ActiveCell.Value <> CurrentTable Then
                    Selection.Offset(-1, 1).Select                      ' Return to Field Name to continue search for ReqText
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j

        End If
    Loop Until BlankCount > 15

'    Range("F1").Select                                                 ' Print found tables [FOR DEBUG]
'    For i = 0 To ToKeepSize
'        ActiveCell.Value = ToKeep(i)
'        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
'    Next i
'    ActiveCell.Value = CStr(ToKeepSize)

    For i = 0 To 1                                  ' Prepare Table for Flag Columns
        Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Next i
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Import Controlled?"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Delete it?"
    Columns("A:F").AutoFit

    BlankCount = 0
    Dim ImportControl As Boolean
    ImportControl = False
    Range("C1").Select
    Do                                              ' Flag necessary columns
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
        Else
            For i = 0 To ToKeepSize
                If ActiveCell.Value = ToKeep(i) Then
                    Selection.Offset(0, -2).Value = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Loop Until BlankCount > 15

    Range("A1").Select                              ' Sort to push all required tables to top of file
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:F")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1").Select

    Do
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

    MyBox = MessageBox.Show("Stuff", "Title")

    Dim file As String
    file = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Dim Word As Object: Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Word.Visible = True

    Set docWD = Word.Documents.Add


    docWD.SaveAs file & "\" & "dictionary", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), "F1").Copy
    Word.Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show` is VB.Net. Even though you have tagged it as VB.Net, I believe you are doing this in VBA.

Try this

```
MyBox = MsgBox("Stuff", vbInformation, "Title")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
Is there a way I can use VB.Net in an Excel macro?
Or can I specify the type of buttons I want in MSGBOX?

Comment: No you cannot use VB.Net in VBA Macro. Yes you can specify the types of buttons in `MSGBOX`. Simply type `msgbox` and then press SPACE and intellisense will prompt you. The 2nd option will let you choose the type of messagebox. For example `vbYesNoCancel`